# Run FFMPEG command with commas and single quotes

Tags: mobile-ffmpeg

I am using [FFMPEG-Kit](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit) for iOS BUT this issue applies to all releases of [FFMPEG-Kit](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit)... within my command I run `[1:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(X,Y)'[withOpacitySet]` but it does not work, if I run the command without that it runs fine...

Is it the commas? The quotation marks?

Comment: define "it does not work" ? What error do you get? How do you run it exactly?

Comment: Encapsulate the command in entirety which has commas and single quotes within the double quotes, it should work.

Comment: @Pranjalya for example, like `[1:v]"format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(X,Y)'"[withOpacitySet]`  ?

Comment: Can you show how you execute the command? Is it FFmpegKit.execute()?

Answer (score -1):

with not much information, I am assuming you are missing double quotes in your filter
try

> `[1:v]format=argb,"geq=r='r(X,Y)'":"a='0.75*alpha(X,Y)'[withOpacitySet];"`

if that's not the case please share your input and/or other information.

Comment: That is wrong, I figured it out, but I will give your the 100 points, please just fix the asnwer... 
`[1:v]format=argb,"geq=r='r(X,Y)'":"a='0.75*alpha(X,Y)'[withOpacitySet];"`

Comment: OK, I have updated.